# Is it possible to create a Spring mvc and hibernate web application without creating LocalSessionFactorybean in the applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In hibernate framework, we provide all the database information in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

But if we are going to integrate the hibernate application with spring, we don't need to create the hibernate.cfg.xml file. We can provide all the information in the applicationContext.xml file.

But my question , Is it possible to integrate spring and hibernate using hibernate.cfg.xml without providing the hibernate configuration in  applicationContext.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. 
Create Config class (@Configuration) and initialize Session Factory bean

Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

//creating seession factory object
SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

Now you can Autowire SessionFactory where were you need session.

Comment: Thanks Satyendra Sharma.While using Configuration annotation, I should also add @Bean  annotation to the getSessionFactory method  in HibernateUtil.java class, right ?